# Providing reliable user feedback with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, reliability, user-feedback

I'm writing an application with a GUI frontend (GTK) and an SQLite backend.  When something is changed via the GUI, I want the change to show up in the GUI if and only if it completed successfully in the DB.

- Is watching the return code from `sqlite3_step` for `SQLITE_ERROR` sufficient to ensure that I don't give false feedback to the user?
- If not, are there other steps, such as callbacks or triggers, that would provide additional reliability?
- Is there any way to detect ALL changes to the database, rather than just ones from the program's own connection, so that I could reflect changes to its content in the GUI dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides exception handling... You should reselect the data from the db that the user did commit by clicking on the save button. That way you know for sure that the user sees the right data.

Comment: I like this idea - it's a far easier structure than having the DB use callback hooks whenever something is modified, and I can't think of any hideously convoluted situations that would break it.  (Aside, of course, from multiple clients, which I expect I can resolve through polling at worst.)

Comment: Accepting this one because, while I'm not certain it's necessary, I'm convinced that it's sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are doing a GUI application that modifies information in a SQLite db.

- Not really, you might get `SQLITE_BUSY` if you have threads; `SQLITE_INTERNAL`; etc.
  Check [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html).
  Instead of asking for `SQLITE_ERROR` you could do something like:

`SQLITE_OK` or `SQLITE_DONE` depending on what you are doing.

```
if (ret != SQLITE_OK || ret != SQLITE_DONE)
    //then this is an error.
```

- Don't know in what language are you coding, but I did an abstraction of SQLite in C [here](http://code.google.com/p/database-adt/). You might find it interesting.
- Use [sqlite3_trace()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/profile.html)

Comment: Indeed, anything but OK and DONE would be an error, but are there errors that checking the return values rigorously would miss?

Your ADT is most elegant, thank you for the link!  I am in fact working in C, reading this code will likely point out many details I've missed.

Comment: Indeed, anything but OK and DONE would be an error, but are there errors that checking the return values rigorously would miss?  => Don't think so. What do you have in mind?

About the ADT: Sorry the homepage is in spanish, ask if you need help. np!

Comment: Between babelfish and linguistic similarities, I can handle the Spanish text, but thanks for the consideration all the same!  (At least it wasn't in Japanese, that would have been a deep challenge.)

I have a naturally suspicious mind - trusting that a value got where it was going makes me nervous.  Didn't have any particular scenario at hand, though Theo's answer below reminded me that triggers inside the DB can alter what actually ends up happening, which might in theory under a horribly twisted DB design lead to content that wasn't exactly what was submitted.  I'd want an accurate display.

Comment: Try sqlite3_trace(). It might have what you want.

Comment: Alas, sqlite3_trace() is per connection, just like the rest of the callback hooks.  My third question will not benefit from it, and I don't see any impact it could have on the first two.  A good try though.